# Retrieve documents from cloudant db if they contain a value in an array property

Tags: database, view, cloudant, nosql

This is how I currently do it, is there a better (more performant or simpler) way?

Documents in `Cloudant` db:

1 ..

```
{
  "_id": "someId",
  "_rev": "someRev",
  "title": "someTitle",
  "parentDirectories": [
    '/', '/base_dir'
  ]
}
```

2 ..

```
{
  "_id": "someId2",
  "_rev": "someRev",
  "title": "someTitle2",
  "parentDirectories": [
    '/', '/base_dir'
  ]
}
```

Currently,I have this `view` defined in `Cloudant` and set the `include_docs` parameter to true so the entire object is returned (this is required) ..

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.parentDirectories) {
    for (i = 0; i < doc.parentDirectories.length; i++) {
      emit(doc.parentDirectories[i], {_id: doc._id});
    }
  }
}
```

And would call the `view` using ..

```
/<database>/_design/<design-doc>/_view/my_view?include_docs=true
```

Using `keys` parameter set to: `['/']`, so view returns the 2 documents above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is fine. Creating a index whose keys are the keys from your array is a perfectly good way to retrieve documents that contain a known value. One small iteration is emit `null` as the value, as you are retrieving the whole document at query-time anyway (with `include_docs=true`):

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.parentDirectories) {
    for (i = 0; i < doc.parentDirectories.length; i++) {
      emit(doc.parentDirectories[i], null);
    }
  }
}
```

You could also emit a subset of your document:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.parentDirectories) {
    for (i = 0; i < doc.parentDirectories.length; i++) {
      emit(doc.parentDirectories[i], doc.title);
    }
  }
}
```

meaning that you could avoid using include_docs=true, for a faster response.

Comment: You can also emit the whole document using `emit(doc.parentDirectories[i], doc)` if you need the whole document -- much faster than reading the document using `include_docs=true` but comes at a cost in the on-disk index size.